# Why trigger must ONLY have some test coverage and not >75%

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

According to Apex Developer Guide 'Every trigger must have some test coverage'. Few websites suggested that it should be greater than 0%. What is the minimum coverage required for triggers? Also, why less than 75% is allowed for triggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code coverage metric is applied in different ways depending on the deployment test run selection. If you choose to run only selected tests (instead of all local tests or all tests), you're judged only on the code coverage of the code you're actually deploying (rather than an aggregate across your org).

In that situation, your deployment (again, not the org) must hit 75% total coverage. That's *not* 75% of each *code unit*, but 75% overall. The clause you quote is requiring that your test classes must "touch" each trigger being deployed. It's not an exemption from the 75% metric, but an additional requirement.